# mouseenter and mouseleave dont work in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am testing my website adding some jQuery interaction. I created this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flash').on({
        mouseenter: function (
            $('.flash').hide();
    },
    mouseleave: function  {
        $('.flashOn').show();
    }
});
```

Very simply to fire the flash: http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/index.html but actually I don't have any clue why doesn't work. I debugged a lot but is the same. The div are correctly placed in HTMLas you see, the script is ok (i think) but it wont work, any clue is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` work fine in jQuery when you use the correct syntax:

```
$('.flash').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.flashOn').hide();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.flashOn').show();
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uv7m54ac/)

I am also assuming that the `mouseenter` handler should hide the `.flashOn` element?

Comment: New syntax to me for multiple handlers on the same element, tyvm sir

Comment: i created two classes in the css, one is displayed none (flash On), basically when i mouseover i wish that the image contained in the second div (display none) it would show and hide the"flash" class. but it does not work anyway. i tried yours but dont work. thanks anyway

Comment: hi, it works. ok, sorry for bad explaination.i wanted the second image overlapping and taking place of the first, not beside...i need to fix this but your is ok. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors for mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
$('.flash').on({
   mouseenter: function ( // here should be (){
    $('.flashOn').hide();
   },
   mouseleave: function { // here should be (){
    $('.flashOn').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks, is good. now i got the right syntax as i wrote to andrew,. i just need a little modification in way that the 2 images are not beside but one take place of the other.

Answer (score 0):

final solution

```
$('.flash').on ({
    mouseenter : function (){

    $('.flash').hide();
    $('.flashOn').show();
},
   mouseleave: function  (){
    $('.flashOn').hide();
    $('.flash').show();

 }
});
```

thanks for the  correct syntax, is ok now